# what is the solution about R programming?

Tags: r

I try to solve this problem. but I don't know how to solve it.
I wrote this codes.

```
algae<-read.table('Analysis.txt', header=F, dec = '.',
  col.names=c('season','size','speed','mxPH','mnO2','C1','NO3','NH4','oPO4',
  'Chla','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7'), na.strings=c('XXXXXXX'))
```

but it is not working.
R just showed this.

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>
> Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
>   'Analysis.txt': No such file or directory

what's the problem?

Comment: Try to change your directory using setwd("path/to/my/directory")

Comment: Perhaps "Analysis.txt" is not in your working directory. Check with `getwd()` or set the full path of "Analysis.txt" in `read.table()`.

Comment: Have you set your working directory to the path where "analysis.txt" is stored? You can check if you type `getwd()` into the console. alternatively, I'd try to specify the complete filepath to the file, so for example 'C:/Research/Data/Analysis.txt' if you're using windows. You have to replace "\" with "/" for the path to work.

Answer (score 0):

Often (especially on Windows) it is hard to know the path to a file.  I usually do something like

```
filename <- file.choose()
```

which opens the dialog to let me find the file, then use `filename` instead of typing the file name explicitly, i.e.

```
algae<-read.table(filename, header = FALSE, dec = '.',
  col.names = c('season', 'size', 'speed', 'mxPH', 'mnO2', 'C1',
    'NO3', 'NH4', 'oPO4', 'Chla', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7'), 
  na.strings = 'XXXXXXX')
```

I've also changed `F` to `FALSE`:  `F` is a variable, and might not be `FALSE`.

Comment: From `base::logical`, logical argumnents automatically interpret `F` as `FALSE`. See: `Character strings c("T", "TRUE", "True", "true") are regarded as true, c("F", "FALSE", "False", "false") as false, and all others as NA.`

Comment: @seeellayewhy Set `F <- TRUE; T <- FALSE` and check if that still holds.

Comment: @Roland Wasn't saying you're wrong, just providing further context. It is undoubtedly better practice to err on the safe side as you suggested but my reply quotes directly from the documentation & is factually correct.

Comment: @seeellayewhy But you omitted "`TRUE` and `FALSE` are reserved words denoting logical constants in the R language, whereas `T` and `F` are global variables whose **initial** values set to these." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @seeellayewhy Your comment is not relevant:  the OP wasn't converting a character string to a logical using `as.logical()`.

Answer (score 0):

The file is likely not in your working directory, as others have mentioned. You can use `getwd()` to figure out what is currently set as your directory.

If you would like to define your working directory, say, to the folder where Analysis.txt is held currently, you can use the code below to change the wd and then call on it to load your file.

```
setwd("C:/User/folder/subfolder/") # set directory
mytable <- read.table(paste0(getwd(), "file.txt"), header=F, dec=".")  # call wd & grab file

# load using your code
algae<-read.table(paste0(getwd(), '/Analysis.txt'), header=F, dec = '.',
  col.names=c('season','size','speed','mxPH','mnO2','C1','NO3','NH4','oPO4',
  'Chla','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7'), na.strings=c('XXXXXXX'))
```

Note that I changed your line by adding paste0(getwd(), yourfile.txt) to call upon that working directory when reading the file in. Another note here: R prefers you use `/` instead of `\` but on a Windows machine copying the path will use the latter, so you'll likely need to go through and change each of them in your file path.